# Python: How to pivot this table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer ID':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  'Customer VisitNo':[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2],
                  'Item Code':['A1','A1','A2','A3','A3','A1','B1','B2','B3','B3','B4','B3'],
                  'Item':['Ball','Ball','Bat','Glove','Glove','Ball','Pen','Mouse','Pencil',
                          'Pencil','Paper','Pencil']})
```

[image]

How can I group the table by Customer ID, Customer VisitNo and pivot to get the following table?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `pivot`. You want a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)  like this:

```
In [1684]: df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Customer ID','Customer VisitNo'], as_index=False).agg(','.join)
Out[1684]:

   Customer ID  Customer VisitNo Item Code              Item
0            1                 1     A1,A2          Ball,Bat
1            1                 2     A3,A1        Glove,Ball
2            2                 1  B1,B2,B3  Pen,Mouse,Pencil
3            2                 2     B4,B3      Paper,Pencil
```

From `df.groupby` docs:

> as_index: bool, default True
>
> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index. Only relevant for DataFrame input. as_index=False is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output.

Comment: what's the rationale for `as_index=False`. So that you don't have to reset_index() after?

Comment: Yes. Check my updated answer's last part. I've put this there.

Answer (score 3):

Without drop_duplicate `unique`

```
s=df.groupby(['Customer ID','Customer VisitNo'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x : ','.join(x.unique()))
   Customer ID  Customer VisitNo Item Code              Item
0            1                 1     A1,A2          Ball,Bat
1            1                 2     A3,A1        Glove,Ball
2            2                 1  B1,B2,B3  Pen,Mouse,Pencil
3            2                 2     B4,B3      Paper,Pencil
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer ID':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  'Customer VisitNo':[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2],
                  'Item Code':['A1','A1','A2','A3','A3','A1','B1','B2','B3','B3','B4','B3'],
                  'Item':['Ball','Ball','Bat','Glove','Glove','Ball','Pen','Mouse','Pencil',
                          'Pencil','Paper','Pencil']})

df = df.drop_duplicates() 

result = df.groupby(['Customer ID','Customer VisitNo']).agg( ','.join)
result = result.reset_index()
print(result)
```